# Is there a program that visualize the volume of an audio file by time?

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio

I have some recorded audio files of several nights of sleeping. I need to find out when there is snore sound. It will be much easy to visualize the audio by volume/time. Is there such a software?

Comment: I recommend you to rephrase your question. It may be closed as off-topic as it stnads. Try to adress the problem rather than directly ask for software recommendation

Comment: I think this is off-topic, but not for what @smc said -  It should go on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Audacity. It will give you a visual representation of the volume. It is open source and very good.

http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How about video? Is there a open source program show video thumbnails with audio volume graph?